# Program won't execute functions, but also gives no errors

Tags: c++, function

The code I have compiles without errors, but when through executing the main function, it won't execute the function `printt()`. I used (`cout >> "Test" >> endl;`) to test where it would stop, and I could see that anything that happens inside `printt()` or even after it, won't be printed in the running program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Piece {

public:
int ypos, xpos, index;
string color, kind;

int getY(void)
{
    return ypos;
}

int getX(void)
{
    return xpos;
}

int adjustY(int change)
{
    ypos = ypos + change;
}

int adjustX(int change)
{
    xpos = xpos + change;
}

};


Piece p[24];

void form(void)
{
for (int i = 0; i <= 23; ++i)
{
    if (i < 4)
    {
        p[i].color = "white";
        p[i].ypos = 7;
        p[i].xpos = i * 2;
        p[i].index = i;
        p[i].kind = "peon";

    }

    else if (i < 8)
    {
        int l;
        l = i - 4;
        p[i].color = "white";
        p[i].ypos = 6;
        p[i].xpos = 1 + (l * 2);
        p[i].index = i;
        p[i].kind = "peon";
    }

    else if (i < 12)
    {
        int m;
        m = i - 8;
        p[i].color = "white";
        p[i].ypos = 5;
        p[i].xpos = (m * 2);
        p[i].index = i;
        p[i].kind = "peon";
    }

    else if (i < 16)
    {
        int n;
        n = i - 12;
        p[i].color = "black";
        p[i].ypos = 0;
        p[i].xpos = 1 + (n * 2);
        p[i].index = i;
        p[i].kind = "peon";
    }

    else if (i < 20)
    {
        int pp;
        pp = i - 16;
        p[i].color = "black";
        p[i].ypos = 1;
        p[i].xpos = (pp * 2);
        p[i].index = i;
        p[i].kind = "peon";
    }

    else
    {
        int q;
        q = i - 20;
        p[i].color = "black";
        p[i].ypos = 2;
        p[i].xpos = 1 + (q * 2);
        p[i].index = i;
        p[i].kind = "peon";
    }
}
}


char matrix[8][8];


void printt(void)
{
for (int i = 0; i = 7; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j = 7; ++j)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = '_';
    }
}
for (int c = 0; c <= 23;++c)
{
    int a, b;
    a = p[c].ypos;
    b = p[c].xpos;
    int dec1, dec2;
    if (p[c].kind == "peon")
    {
        dec1 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        dec1 = 2;
    }
    if (p[c].color == "white")
    {
        dec2 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        dec2 = 2;
    }
    switch(dec1)
    {
        case 1:
            switch(dec2)
            {
                case 1:
                    matrix[a][b] = 'o';
                    break;

                case 2:
                    matrix[a][b] = 'x';
                    break;

            }
            break;

        case 2:
            switch(dec2)
            {
                case 1:
                    matrix[a][b] = 'O';
                    break;

                case 2:
                    matrix[a][b] = 'X';
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }

}
cout << "   0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|  X Position (column)(j)" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "0  " << matrix[0][0] << "|" << matrix[0][1] << "|" << matrix[0][2] << "|" << matrix[0][3] << "|" << matrix[0][4] << "|" << matrix[0][5] << "|" << matrix[0][6] << "|" << matrix[0][7] << endl;
cout << "0  " << matrix[1][0] << "|" << matrix[1][1] << "|" << matrix[1][2] << "|" << matrix[1][3] << "|" << matrix[1][4] << "|" << matrix[1][5] << "|" << matrix[1][6] << "|" << matrix[1][7] << endl;
cout << "0  " << matrix[2][0] << "|" << matrix[2][1] << "|" << matrix[2][2] << "|" << matrix[2][3] << "|" << matrix[2][4] << "|" << matrix[2][5] << "|" << matrix[2][6] << "|" << matrix[2][7] << endl;
cout << "0  " << matrix[3][0] << "|" << matrix[3][1] << "|" << matrix[3][2] << "|" << matrix[3][3] << "|" << matrix[3][4] << "|" << matrix[3][5] << "|" << matrix[3][6] << "|" << matrix[3][7] << endl;
cout << "0  " << matrix[4][0] << "|" << matrix[4][1] << "|" << matrix[4][2] << "|" << matrix[4][3] << "|" << matrix[4][4] << "|" << matrix[4][5] << "|" << matrix[4][6] << "|" << matrix[4][7] << endl;
cout << "0  " << matrix[5][0] << "|" << matrix[5][1] << "|" << matrix[5][2] << "|" << matrix[5][3] << "|" << matrix[5][4] << "|" << matrix[5][5] << "|" << matrix[5][6] << "|" << matrix[5][7] << endl;
cout << "0  " << matrix[6][0] << "|" << matrix[6][1] << "|" << matrix[6][2] << "|" << matrix[6][3] << "|" << matrix[6][4] << "|" << matrix[6][5] << "|" << matrix[6][6] << "|" << matrix[6][7] << endl;
cout << "0  " << matrix[7][0] << "|" << matrix[7][1] << "|" << matrix[7][2] << "|" << matrix[7][3] << "|" << matrix[7][4] << "|" << matrix[7][5] << "|" << matrix[7][6] << "|" << matrix[7][7] << "   Y Position (line)(i)" << endl;
cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
cout << "test1" << endl;
form();
cout << "test2" << endl;
printt();
cout << "End of Programm" << endl;
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Please help me, and sorry if I'm doing something dumb, new to programming.

Note : (`"End of Programm"` also isn't printed in the running program)

Comment: Considered using a debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
for (int i = 0; i = 7; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j = 7; ++j)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = '_';
    }
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = '_';
    }
}
```

you created infinite loop

Comment: that's not infinite loop. the loop simply stops without making no single iteration

Comment: it's not :) `i` is checked against condition `i=7` while being equal to zero. since condition is false, it stops

Comment: Even though the answer was right, can somebody explain why? I said "go till i hits 7" and now I'm saying "go while i is under 8", which basically the same. Need theorical explanation.

Comment: mangusta i've just tested it with compiler and it is the infinite loop ;P

Comment: @mangusta, `i = 7` sets `i` to 7 and then the loop checks that the result is `true`. Since the result is `i` and it's now 7, it's `true` when converted to a `bool`.

Comment: oh, yeah it is infinite, sorry : )) confused with `i==7`

Comment: `i=7` gives boolean true

Comment: with `i==7` it will terminate without a single iteration

Comment: no it won't, for loop works while contition is true. with i==7 loop will finish immediately

Comment: Thanks again, was using the for statement with the mindset of another language.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to turn on all warnings for your compiler. If you use g++, the good flag is "-Wall". Other compilers should have similar options.

Compiling with this flag yields several warnings (including the ones that point to problems in loops that Michał Banasiak pointed to). Fixing them will help to make your program working.